# Input box and button have the same width, but I don't want it

Tags: css

html:

```
<form id="personal_info" action="..." method="post">
    <legend>Personal info</legend>
    <p>
        <label for="fullname">Your name: </label>
        <input name="fullname" id="fullname" type="text" tabindex="1" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">Your e-mail: </label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" tabindex="2" />
    </p>
    <p><input id="send" type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
</form>
```

css:

```
form#personal_info {
    background:#dee;
    width:470px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:0;
}
form#personal_info legend {
    font-family:georgia, sans-serif;
    font-size:1.1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:3px solid #fff;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding:3px;
    width:270px;
    background:#fff url(legend.gif) repeat-x center left;
}
form#personal_info label {
    clear:left;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
    color:#888;
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
}
form#personal_info input {
    border:1px solid #fff;
    background:#fff url(legend.gif) repeat-x top left;
    padding-left:0.5em;
    margin-bottom:0.6em;width:300px;
}
form#personal_info #button1 {
    color:#c00;
    padding-right:0.5em;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-left:8px;
    width:100px;
}
form#personal_info #button1:hover {
    background-position:center left;
    color:#000;
    width:100px;
}
```

Input and button have the same width of 300px, but I want button to be 100px wide. What's wrong?

Comment: I don't see any buttons or anything that matches your submit element in the CSS that would tell it to be 100px

Comment: @DSblizzard I hope you understood what was the mistake.

Comment: Yes, I think. I replaced 'id="send"' to 'id="button1"'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M4g8q/)**

If you just apply style to `input` it will apply those styles to all the `input` element such as `textbox`,`button` as they are input elements.

You should use `id's` to apply styles uniquely.

Using `#button` doesnot mean these styles will be applied to `buttons`.

What you can do is asign id's to your input elements and then apply styles accordingly

```
<input id="txtEmail" type="text"/>
<input id="btnSend" type="submit"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
#txtEmail
{
//your styles
}

#btnSend
{
//your styles
}
```

Alternatively you can do something like this

```
input[type="text"]
{
//your styles
}    

input[type="submit"]
{
//your styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which input type the rule should change:

> input[type='text']

Also, if you are using IDs in your CSS #id, you do not need to prefix them with anything - it will not help!